# Why my proof that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x!}{x^x}=1$ is wrong

Tags: limits, fake-proofs, stirling-numbers

It is well known that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x!}{x^x}=0$$But according to the definition of the Stirling numbers of the first kind, the falling factorial could be written as $$(x)_n=\sum_{k=0}^ns(n,k)x^k$$ Where $(x)_n=x(x-1)(x-2)...(x-n+1)$. So shouldn't $(x)_x$ be $x!$ with a $x^x$ term by the falling factorial expansion, making the limit $1$?

Comment: $x^x$ is no polynomial, at all.

Comment: And $x!$ isn't either.

Comment: @ajotatxe Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{x!}{x^x}={\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\cdots}{x\cdot x\cdot x\cdot x\cdots}}=\frac{x-1}{x}\cdot\frac{x-2}{x}\cdots\frac{2}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{x}$$

Where there are $x$ terms in the numerator and denominator.

Cancelling the first term in both, we see that the limit approaches $0$ as each term in the product approaches $1/x$ with $x\to\infty$

To see that it cannot be $1$, note that you have an infinite product of numbers between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: You need to be really careful. Squeeze theorem is your friend here.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio And the last two terms would be $2/x$ and $1/x$, both of which tend to $0$.

Comment: @LanierFreeman Ah, ok, as in $x!/x^x\le\frac1x$ because everything else $\le1$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Exactly

Comment: Plus x/2 terms less than 1/2.

Comment: One question before accepting and upvoting - what is wrong with dividing $x^x$ in the expansion and taking the limit of each term? Won't I get $s(x,x)$?

Comment: Could you type that out? I believe the error is that the falling factorial is for polynomials--in the case that $x\to\infty$, the formula would no longer apply as it is not a polynomial since it has infinitely many terms.

Comment: @KamalSaleh $\lvert s(n,k)\rvert$ is largest when $k<n$ (although the specific maximizer $k_n$ is kind of out of my depth). For instance, $s(n,1)=(-1)^n(n-1)!$, while $s(n,n)=1$.

Comment: @LanierFreeman That was all I needed. Thanks!